# "heat.stack.list()" to list all stack within the openstack "admin" cred

Tags: python-2.7, openstack, heat

I have source the admin credentials.
I want to list the heat stack running in all the tenant, is that possible ?

for now, I am fetching the name the stack from JSON, and pulling out the id, after sourcing specific tenant cred.

```
def heat_id(heat,stack_name):
    stack_id = str(heat.stacks.get(stack_name).id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenStack Heat stack resources are isolated under a Tenant. To get the entire list of running stacks, you should do it by iterating the tenant's list and then make a stack list call with filtered status = active. 
Note: User who does this execution should be given permission to required tenant's (probably in your case it all tenant's)